# My spinner isn't visible while using an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have a `TabView` in android.  The first tab has an `Image` and a `Spinner`.  The `Spinner` is a simple list that shows up in the first tab if there is no image, but disappears when the `Image` is there.

Update:
I've figured out that the imageView is 'pushing' the spinner out of the frame.  I just needed to make my image a "background view"

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

keep the spinner inside a Layout (ex. FrameLayout) and set the image as background for that Layout.

Comment: You were right...I was in the iPhone mindset thinking that they would just 'stack'.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using

```
LinearLayout
```

as base Layout which hosts `ImageView` and `Spinner`.

the default orientation of `LinearLayout` is horizontal..

change it to vertical just by adding

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

to `<LinearLayout >` tag